# Menu Block: Expand all children of this tree - ignored?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

Is anybody using Taxonomy Menu + Menu Block? I have a problem setting `Expand all children of this tree`, in that it seems to be completely ignored. My sidebar taxonomy menu lists all children expanded, regardless of the setting value.

Since I don't see the problem in issue queue for the project, I assume this could be only a local problem. It might be that I am overlooking some other module that could be causing that.

Open for your insights, please.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Bug was dependant of my theme which have a theme_menu_link preprocess function. If I delete this function and clear cache, menu block works as designed.
To be quickly sure, enabled bartik and look the behavior of your menu block.

@see http://drupal.org/node/1425342#comment-5679426

Comment: Thanks for your note. THe site is still at 7.9 which - I assume from a quick glimpse at the issue link - should not be bitten by that bug. Actually, in my case it was probably due to a conflict between some taxonomy and breadcrumb-related modules. I had a couple of them installed just for testing purposes. THey apparently did not like dancing one with another.